# jQuery + console (Firebug): check selector

Tags: jquery, debugging, firebug

I'm trying to use console.log("item") to find out if my selector is correct, what is the best way to go about just trying to "trace" a selector?

```
console.log(my-jQuery-selector);
```

Comment: Have you considered doing this in FB's console? I know this might be a little obvious, but I totally missed the console in my first 9 weeks or so of developing with jQuery. Now I use it constantly.

Comment: melee's comment should really have been the answer. Not sure how I missed it - the FireBug console rocks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also type directly in the console. For example I can write in the console:

```
var test = $('.myselector'); /return
test /return
```

and it will output the result.

Comment: You can just write the raw selector $('.myselector') - slightly faster when you're trying to find a tricky one :)

Comment: That's true.  I was just trying to demonstrate the flexibility and power of the console :)

Comment: You're absolutely right. I freaking love the console, it has saved my life (sanity) many a time.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 $(function() {
     var my_jQuery_selector = $('.tabs ul li'); //or any other selector
     console.log(my_jQuery_selector);
 });
```

Comment: It's returning NOTHING...does that mean my selector is null or invalid?

Comment: I don't see square brackets or anything! I take it that's null?